# Create List of enum by field from comma separated String in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some enum and I need to create a List of enum from a comma-separated String. Enum is defined through an additional field. I have:

```
public enum ReceiverFields {
    FIRST_NAME("firstName"),
    LAST_NAME("lastName"),
    MIDDLE_NAME("middleName");

    private String code;

    private ReceiverFields(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<EnumFields> enumFields = null;
        enumFields = getReceiverFields("enumFirst,enumSecond,enumThird");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enumFields.toArray()));

        enumFields = getReceiverFields("enumFirst,enumThird,somethingOther");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enumFields.toArray()));

        enumFields = getReceiverFields("");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enumFields.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<EnumFields> getReceiverFields(String receiverFields) {
        if (receiverFields == null) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

        String[] values = receiverFields.split(",");

        List<EnumFields> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(values.length);
        for (String value : values) {
            for (EnumFields enumField : EnumFields.values()) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(enumField.getCode())) {
                    valuesList.add(enumField);
                }
            }
        }

        return valuesList;
    }
}
```

How I can use stream instead of the loop For?

---

***Edit*** ([from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190755/create-list-of-enum-by-field-from-comma-separated-string-in-java/58191847#comment102762091_58190755)):

I seem to have decided:

```
List<EnumFields> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(values.length); 
Arrays.stream(values).forEach(v -> (Arrays.stream(EnumFields.values())
      .filter(e -> (e.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(v))) 
      .findFirst()) .ifPresent(valuesList::add)); Right?
```

Comment: Please show us your attempts and where you're struggling.

Comment: Hello, @Flown ) I seem to have decided:
        `List<EnumFields> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(values.length);
        Arrays.stream(values).forEach(v ->
                (Arrays.stream(EnumFields.values())
                        .filter(e -> (e.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(v)))
                        .findFirst())
                        .ifPresent(valuesList::add));`
Right?

Comment: What’s this `Arrays.toString(collection.toArray())` I now see popping up in question code so often? What’s wrong with `collection.toString()` or in case of printing, the even simpler `System.out.println(enumFields);`? Is there some article or tutorial advertising the unnecessary copy operation?

Comment: By the way, why yo you show us the `ReceiverFields` definition when you then use an entirely different `EnumFields` type? It’s not only the mismatching class name, the values “*enumFirst,enumSecond,enumThird*” are unrelated to “*firstName, lastName,* or *middleName*”. Besides that, every programmer should be aware of [this article](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)…

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `forEach` as mentioned in the attempt, you can make use of `flatMap` and ternary operator as :

```
public static List<ReceiverFields> getReceiverFields(String receiverFields) {
    return receiverFields == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Arrays.stream(receiverFields.split(","))
            .flatMap(value -> Arrays.stream(ReceiverFields.values())
                    .filter(enumField -> value.equalsIgnoreCase(enumField.getCode())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```